After upgrade from .NET 8 to .NET 9 EmailConfirmation is not working
I have code like this when a user registers:
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("confirmemail", "home", new { userId = user.Id, code }, HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

// This code in here it is working
var result2 = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

But when I copy the callbackUrl and call from the browser, it is not able to confirm the user.
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

if (user == null)
    return View("Error");

var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

Has anyone encountered this issue after upgrade from .NET 8 to .NET 9?

"... it is not able to confirm the user" Why is that? Is there an error in the browser? or ... ??

There is no error, the result when execute _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code); Is Failed: Invalid Token

This question is similar to: Invalid Token. while verifying email verification code using UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user.Id, code). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different (there are probably more differences than just the .NET version?) and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Accoriding to your scenario, after upgrading to .NET 9, make sure the email confirmation URL is correctly encoded, the token hasn't expired, and the HttpContext.Request.Scheme is correct. Check for binding issues, review Identity settings, and log errors for further insights.

I notice, we need to UrlEncode the code before sending the email
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
var encodedCode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("confirmemail", "home", new { userId = user.Id, code = encodedCode }, HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

